# Probability choosing the right answer on second question

Tags: probability

Assume you answer the first question in this exam by choosing one of the four answers uniformly at random. You answer the second question by choosing, again uniformly at random, one of the three answers you did not choose in the first question. What is the probability that you answer the second question correctly?

1. $\frac{1}{3}$,
2. $\frac{1}{4}$,
3. $\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}$,
4. None.

I think it's 1. because we only have 3 choices and out of three, one is correct one.

Comment: Hint2: you have to regard, whether you choose in the first question the number of answer, which is the right number, or not, for the second question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we're choosing a random answer, the probability will be $\frac{1}{4}$ (it doesn't matter that we can't guess one of the answers). Here's a more spelled out argument if you don't believe that.

Since we assume that each of four answers are equally likely to be the correct one, we can assume (by symmetry) that we answer choice $a$ on the first guess. Then, we have two cases:

Case 1: The answer is $a$ for the second question. This happens with probability $\frac 14$, and there is no chance that we get it right.

Case 2: The answer is $b, c,$ or $d$. This happens with probability $\frac{3}{4}$ and we have a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance to get it right.

Thus, the desired probability is $\frac{1}{4} (0) + (\frac{3}{4})(\frac{1}{3}) = \frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

Since you are picking at random, making no distinction between the possible answers, any of the 4 answers are equally likely to be selected as an answer to the second question. Since there are 4 possible answers, the probability is  $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4! ways to answer the 4 questions.
After you pick the correct answer for Question 2, there are 3! ways to answer the other 3 questions.

So the probability of answering question 2 correctly is $\frac{3!}{4!}=\frac{1}{4}$